# TuesPechkin adding Â in front of Currency £ Symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, tuespechkin

I have been using Tues Pechkin for html to PDF Conversion
 But there is one issue
 Tues Pechkin is adding by default Â this symbol in front of  £ Symbol

Example :- `Â£85,000`

```
var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
            {
                GlobalSettings =
    {
        ProduceOutline = true,
        DocumentTitle = "TEST",
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4, // Implicit conversion to PechkinPaperSize
        Margins =
        {
            All = 1.375,
            Unit = Unit.Centimeters
        }
}}
```

Please help 
Thanku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added a new Websettings

```
new ObjectSettings { HtmlText = strContent,
         WebSettings = new WebSettings
                        {
                            DefaultEncoding = "UTF-8",
                            LoadImages = true,
                            PrintBackground = true
                        }
                    }
```

So that it can accept UTF-8 character ,And it is resolved. Thanku